# in appsettings.production.json, what is the exclude section?

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

in VS 2019, aspnet core 3.1, I created appsettings.Productions.json.

Why did the contain the following, and what does it mean?

```
"exclude": [
    "**/bin",
    "**/bower_components",
    "**/jspm_packages",
    "**/node_modules",
    "**/obj",
    "**/platforms"
]
```

Comment: It is used to exclude list of folders to let the language service know which files are safe to ignore.

Comment: @Rena - I apologize, but I do not know what a language service means.  Are you saying that during the publication to production, these are the folders to ignore?

Comment: Hi @Ron,That's it.

Comment: @Rena - thanks (BTW - why didn't you put it in answers instead of comments?  If you did, I could upvote your answer) - PS if you copy and paste into answer and I will upvote you

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did the contain the following, and what does it mean?

It is used to exclude list of folders to let the language service know which files are safe to ignore.

The output location, as well as non-project folders such as `node_modules` or `bin`, should be added to this setting.